# He wrote more novels than she (wrote) songs

Tags: ellipsis, comparative-constructions, comparative

He wrote 5 novels, and she wrote 4 songs.
I think you can say:

> a. He wrote more novels than she wrote songs.
>
> b. He wrote more novels than she did songs.

Since the verb is repeated, can you omit it?

> c. He wrote more novels than she songs.

Is c. grammatical even if it's not as natural? Or is it ungrammatical? If it's ungrammatical, why?

Comment: c. is incorrect

Comment: _c_ is less natural than the others, though it seems no less "correct" than, "He teaches science and she music". The awkwardness comes from the strong expectation of a final **verb**. "she songs" _sounds like_ a wonky verb! "She eats more fish than I meat, more eggs than he rolls."

Comment: @OldBrixtonian How about _He wrote novels and she songs_ and _He teaches science better than she music_?

Answer (score 1):

While c) would seem to follow the principles of parallelism, it is not a natural construction. The verb should not be omitted, though it may be replaced with a form of "do".

So c) is not correct.  I don't know if "why" is ever a good question when grammar is in question, but I speculate that it is because English doesn't distinguish nouns from verbs by the word endings. So "...than she songs" appears to be a verb "to song" which is an error.

Comment: If it's because "songs" appears to be a verb, how about _He wrote more novels than she poems_?

Comment: Still looks like a verb "to poem". But asking "why" for any grammar rule is pointless.  Language doesn't have a "why".

Comment: Native speakers rarely need to investigate the why, but others do much more often. Also, whenever native speakers can easily explain the why, they don't dismiss why questions as pointless.

Answer (score 1):

> c. He wrote more novels than she songs.

We could consider adding a [gapping comma](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/gapping#:%7E:text=The%20gapping%20comma%20is%20very,earlier%20in%20the%20same%20sentence.) to reduce ambiguity.

> We use a gapping comma to show that one or more words have been left out when the missing words would simply repeat the words already used earlier in the same sentence.

> c. He wrote more novels than she, songs.

With this comma, *songs* would be less likely to be interpreted as a verb.